# Navigate from one LWC to another LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have two lightning web components and I have to navigate from one LWC to another LWC on button click.

I tried navigation service to apply the NavigationMixin function in the component’s base class to extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement). but it didn't work.

Can please anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (yet).

[List of all interesting PageReference types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) says you're supposed to use `standard__component` but the target can't be pure LWC. At best it has to be hidden inside an Aura wrapper.

> A Lightning component. To make an addressable Lightning web component,
>   embed it in an Aura component that implements the
>   [lightning:isUrlAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) interface.

It's a pain. I suspect that's also reason why we can't make quick actions with LWC yet, they'd have to be wrapped in Aura.

Click the link in the quote, it'll lead you to example how to pass parameters (`/lightning/cmp/c__helloTarget?c__firstname=John`)

Comment: Luckily, we can now :)

Comment: @Akhil, I still couldn't find how we can. can you post any link pls ?

Comment: check this official doc, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types

Answer (score 0):

I have had the similar issues . I have been trying to navigate to an LWC from another in a community and it looks like :
In communities, only comm__namedPage page-reference will work.

Comment: not really, you can check my solution for details on how to navigate from one page to another on simple button click.

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce LWC app, you can navigate from one LWC component to another (which is on another tab/apppage) with the following code

**myComponent.html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="0" onclick={navigateNext}>Click Here</a>
```

**myComponent.js**

```
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
    import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

    export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){

        @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

        @api tabName = "NextPage";
        navigateNext() {
            console.log("tabName = ", this.tabName)
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]
                ({
                    type: 'standard__navItemPage',
                    attributes: {
                        apiName: this.tabName
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Please replace the `tabName` variable with the apppage/tab name you are supposed to navigate.

That's it. You will be navigated to the `tabName` specified when you click the `button` in html

**You can also go through the official documentation for more** : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_basic

Answer (score 0):

In LWC Application, We can do it in either of the following ways:

**1. Using Container Component**

Create a parent LWC component that will be containing both the lwc components and showing one of the components at a time.

On clicking of the button, dispatch a custom event to navigate between the components.
On receiving the custom event in the container component, hide the visible component and show another.

**2. Making use of LWC routes.**

For information on lwc routes follow the below link.

http://lwc-router.com/#/quickstart